# breakpoint is triggered from cout?

Tags: c++

so i'm trying to write an implementation of the Huffman algorithm, but i'm getting an error inside the function responsible to print the characters and their encodings, while trying to print the coded value of a char. specifically it looks like `cout` throwing an exception but i cant get my head around what's the cause.

the function `printEncoded` gets a node in the huffman tree, the depth of that node in the tree, and an already dynamicaly allocated `int` array with a size of the number of characters, named `code`.
it returns essentially the number of bits used to encode the file.

main:

```
int main()
{
    string filename;

    cout << "please enter name of file: " << endl;
    //cin >> filename;

    //debug
    filename = "input1.txt";

    BSTree tr = buildTree(filename); //function that builds a binary search tree from the chars in 'filename'

    Node* res = huffman(tr); //exporting the the char values and instances from 'tr' to a minimum heap and rebuilding it using huffman algorithm

    int* code = new int[tr.getNumOfObjects()]; //tr.getNumOfObjects() returns the number of different chars in 'tr'

    cout << "Character encoding: " << endl;
    int weight = printEncoded(res,0,code);

    cout << endl << "Encoded file weight : " << setprecision(4) << weight << " bits" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the function:

```
int printEncoded(Node* tr, int depth, int* code)
{
    if (tr != NULL)
    {
        if (tr->getLeftChild() == NULL && tr->getRightChild() == NULL) //is a leaf
        {
            cout << "'" << tr->getData() << "' - ";
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
            {
                cout << code[i];  //breakpoint triggered here
            }
        
            cout << endl;

            //returning length of the code * char instances
            return (tr->getFrequency() * depth);
        }
        else
        {
            int freqSum;
            code[depth] = 0;
            freqSum = printEncoded(tr->getLeftChild(), depth + 1, code);
            code[depth] = 1;
            freqSum += printEncoded(tr->getRightChild(), depth + 1, code);
            return freqSum;
        }
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

`Node` is a class for the Huffman tree node:

```
class Node

    {
    private:
        int frequency;
        char data;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    }
```

Comment: What is `code`? It looks likely that `depth` would become larger than the length of the array pointed to by `code`.

Comment: Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: I believe the answer is most likely correct. Your `depth` being passed is invalid causing out of bounds access to your code array.

Comment: @drescherjm The deceleration and initialization of `code` in main is still not shown, and the question still does not contain a [MCVE]. Please take a few minutes to read the linked article.

Comment: You need to verify that `tr.getNumOfObjects()` is correct. Perhaps the bug is this returns 0.

Comment: ok so i read the article and tried to go by it.. hope now its good..
in any case, i'm guessing its not related to the array length since the height of the tree would be worse case scenario O(number of different chars), plus i tried a little manipulation where instead of the  cout << code[i] i wrote int temp = code[i] and got a legal value, but then when i tries cout<<temp the error poped up again

Comment: ***i'm guessing its not related to the array length*** Your debugger disagrees with your guess. My advice is to single step through your code looking at your variables at each step starting with the `int* code = new int[tr.getNumOfObjects()];` line so no guessing is needed. You will see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @drescherjm you were right! after exiting 'huffman' function the distractor was called on 'tr'..  i switched lines between the huffman function call and the array allocation and now it works fine. thanks for the help!

Comment: i still find it odd that when i tried 'temp = code[i]' no reading violation was called... any idea on what the reason might be for future references?

Comment: Doing something that causes Undefined Behavior does not mean it will be detected by the debugger or crash. In the worst case your program will work as you expected giving you no hint that the program was broken then randomly crash when you are showing the completed project to your boss or client.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is happening at runtime, on the line

```
cout << code[i];  //breakpoint triggered here
```

the only possible reason is that the i index is outside of the bound of the array. Check the caller code to fix the depth parameter to be within the int array passed with the code parameter

Edit:

try to replace this code into the main and see what is the size of the code array

```
int sizeofCode = tr.getNumOfObjects();
cout << "sizeof code = " << sizeofCode << endl;
int* code = new int[sizeofCode]; //tr.getNumOfObjects() returns the number of different chars in 'tr'

cout << "Character encoding: " << endl;
int weight = printEncoded(res, sizeofCode, code);
```

Comment: for some odd reason it happens on the first iteration of the 'for' loop, and i allocated the array in advance. i edited the question

Comment: Your edit did not help for the reason @FrançoisAndrieux mentioned.

Comment: You code needs at minimum to show were, how and what size is allocated for the `code` array since the allocated size seems to be smaller or equal to the `depth` variable.

Comment: calling the code with depth = 0, the cout << code[i]; wold never be executed, since i < depth would be false when entering the loop (0 < 0 ).

Comment: edited again with the main.. i hope now its ok. please inform me if there is any data missing

Comment: It's difficult to debug without the code :) Try to change the main as I suggested in my edit and let's see what is the size of the code array

Comment: yep as @drescherjm pointed out above the problem was indeed in the allocation.. distractor was called and thats why i was actually allocating ileagal value for the array.. thanks for the help!